# "An error occurred while processing this directive"

Tags: php, file-upload

I cannot upload large files. I've set `php.ini` as such:

```
max_execution_time = 3600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 100M
post_max_size = 100M
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

It returns a 500 error: `an error occurred while processing this directive`

Why is this?  And more importantly, how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500 error is not an error itself, it's just a banner that reads "There is an error somewhere! See error log for the details".

Looks like it's not a php problem, but a web-server one. But I hate to guess anyway. Better to take a look into error log.

Comment: @Syom In the `logs` directory of your web server. If you're on shared hosting, you'll need to look into the control panel, or talk to the provider.

Comment: @Syom if it's windows and apache installed in default location, it's "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\logs\error.log"

Answer (score 0):

It could be SSI problem. Maybe your webserver is having a problem to read some scripts which have SSI commands in it. Try to take a look at the configuration.
If you use Apache, try to check the AddHandler setting.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a shared server, I imagine the admins are overriding your ini settings. Use http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php to confirm your settings are actually taking effect.