# Wordpress large file upload error

Tags: php, wordpress, file, upload, media

I am trying to upload large files using the built-in uploader (1 gig or more.) However, I sometimes (randomly) get HTTP upload errors. They are more frequent the larger the file is.

I am having problems with files larger than 100 MB.

In php.ini, I have set:

```
file_uploads
upload_max_filesize
max_input_time
memory_limit
max_execution_time
post_max_size
```

...to 1.2gb with 600 seconds time limits.

An upload of 130mb lasts 15 minutes but still fails.
The AJAX response is:

```
<!-- SHTML Wrapper - 500 Server Error -->
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

Is this because I am on a shared server plan? If I move to a VPS will this problem stop?

---

Update:

I have tried some FTP plugins, and uploading via the standard WordPress Browser Uploader and I get the same error:

```
[an error occurred while processing this directive]
```

My only problem is with integrating some sort of ftp solution in WordPress itself. My client does not want to use a separate method for uploading. He would rather have it all in the WP Admin.

I've been looking for better FTP Uploader plugins but they all seem to be un-supported for a few years. Is there no way at all to make it work within WordPress? If I move the site to a VPS will still face the same limitations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [uploading problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613181/uploading-problem)

Comment: I'd say that any hosting company you pay should be able to help with this from their side. Looks like you've gone in the right direction with the ini file.

Answer (score 0):

I would use http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php function to see what effective settings PHP is using. On shared servers, many PHP ini settings are locked down and you can't change them without being root.

Yes, on a virtual private server, you will typically have root access which means you can do anything you want. I recommend Amazon's EC2 if you want to go that route. A dedicate micro instance will run you about $20/month, but it will give you root access and 100% control over customization. The performance will be on par with a shared hosting service like Bluehost or other cpanel based hosting solutions.

Answer (score -1):

Check your phpinfo() file and see if the settings are activated. You may have edited wrong php.ini file.